# Create endpoint HTTP Rest on cloud

Tags: cloud, bots, whatsapp, endpoint, ngrok

I'm starting to programming bot in whatsapp and I want to create one so that my family can use, but here's is the problem, I use ngrok to create my endpoint URL, so I make my machine into a host, and that's the problem, because when I turn off ngrok in my machine, the bot stops working. So is that a way to make a stable endpoint to be stored in cloud, so I can use my bot 24h a day?

Comment: I guess you need to have a server

Comment: Host the bot on something like AWS, Digitalocean, Google Cloud or Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to find a site that wouldn't ask for my credit card info, not the case of aws, google cloud, and others, thanks to comments I founded heroku where you can use heroku server to lauch your API totaly free and don't request for your credit card. Basically you have follow the steps:

1. Create your heroku account and download heroku CLI;
2. Setup your app directory as a git repository;
3. Create a new Heroku app;
4. Deploy your app to heroku;

There you go, your API is on cloud.
For more details check on https://github.com/nikhilkumarsingh/WhatsAppBotTut

Comment: You should [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so that the question does not appear still open.